# How do I see the codebase of a forta bot?

Tags: untagged

I'm looking at a [forta bot](https://ipfs.forta.network/ipfs/QmW2dyzGVqyiA83jXRfUpxQ6v36zpDfF61H4G4H4dsNUkT) on the [forta explorer](https://explorer.forta.network/bot/0xe39e45ab19bb1c9a30887e157a21393680d336232263c96b326f68fa57a29723).

How would I see what the codebase of this specific bot is?

For example:

```
{
manifest: {
from: "0xE48CA5319BBfcb0B1b8Cc4981aA56d39419D9f2d",
name: "blocksec-bot",
agentId: "blocksec-bot",
agentIdHash: "0xe39e45ab19bb1c9a30887e157a21393680d336232263c96b326f68fa57a29723",
version: "0.07",
timestamp: "Fri, 28 Apr 2023 10:18:25 GMT",
imageReference: "bafybeicfb2wcsee7lghlnjewpdzvwdlfyockguuxg5cvghgljtv2z6qeay@sha256:73c8cfabc4b7bf08326013e1d9129a3f88465a96b51e467e7ea87fd0a6c46d5f",
documentation: "QmYCVwuWuiWGEetbw5g9xVtNo7Ng1rXWxaBZr74z7SMKbb",
repository: "",
projects: [ ],
chainIds: [
1,
10,
56,
137,
42161,
43114
],
publishedFrom: "Forta Explorer 0.0.2"
},
signature: "0xeaec77df5d0a7cf796a64909e6d91a2c3c52eb59ab57b5f22a396fc8b5df1d6b5c01f0c6028f6e0a9b2b156be525a500d2a2246b3f3fae0cdc31c23b772f6a2a1b"
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Click on the little image callout, which gets you to the [json](https://ipfs.forta.network/ipfs/QmW2dyzGVqyiA83jXRfUpxQ6v36zpDfF61H4G4H4dsNUkT)
2. From there, extract the image hash:

```
bafybeicfb2wcsee7lghlnjewpdzvwdlfyockguuxg5cvghgljtv2z6qeay@sha256:73c8cfabc4b7bf08326013e1d9129a3f88465a96b51e467e7ea87fd0a6c46d5f
```

3. pull the docker container with:

```
docker pull disco.forta.network/bafybeicfb2wcsee7lghlnjewpdzvwdlfyockguuxg5cvghgljtv2z6qeay@sha256:73c8cfabc4b7bf08326013e1d9129a3f88465a96b51e467e7ea87fd0a6c46d5f
```

But even then, you'd have to inspect the docker image.

Unless a protocol directly gives you the github repo associated with a forta bot, you'd have to decompile the docker image.